# Spy on process.stdout and process.stdin in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, file-descriptor

Is it possible to capture everything my app is outputting `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` and taking `process.stdin` into a file without affecting the output or input (without affecting or redirecting the output or input and keeping everything as is before adding this spy code).

Comment: Would the `tee` program suit your needs?  It can be used as part of a unix pipe to write stream output or input to file, and pass along the stream as is.

Comment: @MaxFriederichs I need something internally

Comment: @faressoft please explain what is the actual goal? Do you need to have this in the same process?

Comment: The most obvious goal is to use in testing such as having a mocha spec verify that the correct log message was actually sent to `process.stdout`.